# Update multiple data in single array element using object id using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am Very Beginner in mongodb.I have mongodb data with multiple array elements just update multiple data in single array element

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("6217138f0607ea2e07e70b25"),
        "phone_number" : "7645645676",
        "email" : "test02@gmail.com",
        "name" : "John",
        "address" : "44th street Englan",
        "devices" : [
                {
                        "ime_number" : "123456789012345",
                        "device_name" : "Test456356",
                        "subscription_type" : "Yearly",
                        "validity" : 365,
                        "_id" : ObjectId("6217138f0607ea2e07e70b26"),
                    
                },
                {
                        "ime_number" : "HHH555",
                        "device_name" : "Harry Potter",
                        "subscription_type" : "Monthly",
                        "validity" : 32,
                        "_id" : ObjectId("621714570607ea2e07e70b2b"),
                     
                }
        ]
```

Only This data

```
"ime_number" : "123456789012345",
"device_name" : "Test456356",
"subscription_type" : "Yearly",
"validity" : 365,
```

Changed data

```
"ime_number" : "888844442222",
"device_name" : "Remote Device",
 "subscription_type" : "Monthly",
 "validity" : 30,
```

Help me to solve this

Comment: What is the question can you be more clear?

Comment: Thanks for your response Just update data like ime_number ,device_name ,subscription_type ,validity particular array element using object id

Comment: How do you find the particular element? Using device name?

Comment: I have object id, using object id only update all data

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator to do this.

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

Now you have two options, to either update the individual fields (only the ones you want to) or update the whole object. For both of them you need [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) :

Just pass the query as first argument of your `update` query and the second argument is your update clause.

```
Collection.update({'devices.device_name' : 'Test456356'}, {
{ '$set': { 'devices.$': {
"ime_number" : "888844442222",
"device_name" : "Remote Device",
 "subscription_type" : "Monthly",
 "validity" : 30,
} } }
});
```

Note: above updates all the elements found with the query. If you want to be specific you can use `updateOne`. Just replace `update` with [`updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) and it will update the first matched document

Comment: Its possible {'devices.device_name' : 'Test456356'} instead of {'devices._id' : ObjectId("6217138f0607ea2e07e70b26")}

Comment: Yes. actually i posted the answer before you put the comment

Comment: Are you able to get it to work? @John

Comment: Sorry its not working

Comment: Getting any error? Please share. Also did you try with `device_name` first?

Comment: query like this : `Collection.update({'devices._id' : { '$set': { 'devices.$': {
"ime_number" : "888844442222",
"device_name" : "Remote Device",
 "subscription_type" : "Monthly",
 "validity" : 30,
} } }
});`

Comment: uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing } after property list :

Comment: It was only for the query part. Now i have updated the comment with whole command

Comment: Its working when using device name

Comment: But I want update using Object Id

Comment: What about my updated comment did you try that>